# CarrierWave file does not show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

So when I get the image upload, the show page confirms that the registration was successful, but does not show the image. I get:

Charle was successfully updated.

Title: yes

Name: john doe

?1310250102

Edit | Back

This is the error I get in terminal when running the server

```
Started GET "/images/?1310250102" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jul 12 11:42:15 -0400 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images"):


Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware        /templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.1ms)
```

This is what my routes file looks like:

```
Evergreen::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :charles
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seemed to be caused by a piece of code that I picked up from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009550/carrierwave-upload-with-nested-forms/5010677#5010677) and added to my code with out understanding it:

```
  def image=(val)
    if !val.is_a?(String) && valid?
      image_will_change!
      super
    end
  end
```

Do you also happen to be using this code? I removed it completely and that solved the problem!